# CKAN tests error: "KeyError: 'tags'"

Tags: ckan

Tests pass on the CI, but locally I get an error when testing master:

```
$ nosetests --ckan --with-pylons=test-core.ini ckan/tests/logic/action/test_get.py -x
No handlers could be found for logger "ckan.lib.uploader"
.../usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2181: SAWarning: Usage of the 'related attribute set' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  % method)
........................................................................................................................E
======================================================================
ERROR: ckan.tests.logic.action.test_get.TestTagShow.test_tag_show_for_vocab_tag
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/vagrant/src/ckan/ckan/tests/logic/action/test_get.py", line 1857, in test_tag_show_for_vocab_tag
    tag_in_dataset = dataset['tags'][0]
KeyError: 'tags'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 124 tests in 66.301s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I can recreate it more quickly by just running these two tests:

```
nosetests --ckan --with-pylons=test-core.ini ckan/tests/logic/action/test_get.py:TestPackageAutocompleteWithDatasetForm.test_custom_schema_returned ckan/tests/logic/action/test_get.py:TestTagShow.test_tag_show_for_vocab_tag
```

Does anyone else have this problem or is it just me? Has any one got any ideas how to fix it?

(My deps are up-to-date, having done: `pip install -r requirements.txt -r dev-requirements.txt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was the test_get.py was not cleaning up properly as there was a missing call to the teardown. Fix: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/4371